# Django how to use serializer with models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to use save() function in my model to auto populate the field via use of the api.. here is the code(models.py:

```
from .views import savee
class SaveRushh(models.Model):

    keyword = models.ForeignKey(KW)    
    u1 = models.URLField()    
    u2 = models.URLField()

    def save():
        savee(keyword)
```

And the function itself:

```
from .serializer import RushSerializer

def savee(keyword):

nov = {'u1': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow', 'u2': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_color'}
nov['keyword'] = keyword    
serializer = RushSerializer(data=nov)

if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
```

And here is serializer code:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import SaveRushh

class RushSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # key = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = SaveRushh        
        fields = ('keyword', 'u1', 'u2')
```

When I try to run it it gives this error:

> File ".../serializer.py", line 2, in 
>       from .models import SaveRushh ImportError: cannot import name SaveRushh

I think I understand that what I've done is something like circular import(SaveRushh already exists in models)

I just can't think of a good way to get around it.

To make it more clear, I want save() function inside my model to be ran every time model is created/updated, calling another function that uses rest api to populate model with data.

Comment: Why does `savee` live in views? Why can't it just be inside the model save method?

Comment: You are right, I moved the code but this still doesn't fix the problem.

If I call serializer from models.py in any way(not even directly) it gives the error.

Comment: Looks like an circular import to me. Try to import RushSerializer within savee.

Comment: `RushSerializer` will automatically save you model when you call `save` method, so no need to override the model `save` itself..